# Why is `@PreAuthorize` not protecting my service method?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a web app built with Java Spring MVC and uses Spring Security for logging in.  Sign in/out works great.  There are two user roles "ROLE_ADMIN" and "ROLE_USER".

I want to ensure my method `userService.createUser(username)` is only accessible by users who have the "ROLE_ADMIN" role.

I added a `@PreAuthorize` annotation like so ...

```
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    public Integer createUser(String username) throws Exception {
        /* .... */
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

... but that's not preventing a logged in user with only "ROLE_USER" from creating a user.

I googled and read about annotation `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` but I can't figure out where it goes.

Do I annotate my UserService class with it?  Or, the WebController?  Or both?

Please help because I could really use some advice!

Comment: `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` is a configuration and it goes with any `@Configuration` annotated class. `@Configuration` is more apt , though it works with  `@Component` or its specializations well. [Example](https://spring.io/blog/2013/07/04/spring-security-java-config-preview-method-security/)

Comment: Thanks!  Followed the sample code at the example link and it works!  I'll post the solution as an answer.  Cheers!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution, thanks to the link provided by @R.G ...

I added `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)` to my configuration class like so ...

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
public class AppConfig {
    /* ... */
}
```

And then I added `@PreAuthorize` to the method in the interface like so ...

```
public interface UserService {

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    public Integer createUser(String username) throws Exception;

}
```

Works!  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`EnableGlobalMethodSecurity` is deprecated and replaced by `EnableMethodSecurity` and `prePostEnabled` is `true` by default.

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableMethodSecurity;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class MyApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication, args);
    }
}
```